# What is the DIP IC abbreviation?

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, dip

If I am being correct, DIP means that some microcircuitry is embedded into uniform plastic or ceramic casing, which makes it more robust to physical damage and allows to connect to the breadboard or printed-circuit board in a covenient way given the standartised distance between pins in both X- and Y- planes.

What does the DIP IC abbreaviation means?

(Found it in Jeremy Blum's book: SN74HC595N shift register DIP IC)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no basic research i.e. the first hit on googling  is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry for **possible off-topic**. I get what *DIC abbreviation* stands for with a Google search, but I couldn't quite get what is an *IC*. Now it seems that I get it too - it's just a synonym for *microchip*. That simple)

Comment: First hit on IC gives you the answer. First hit on DIP gives you the answer. As far as I'm aware a *DIC* is something else LOL.

Comment: To me, IC means Integrated Circuit, and "microchip" is  a sort of slang term for Integrated Circuit (as well as being the name of a company that makes ICs.)  I don't think many people who work in electronics would use "microchip" when referring to an IC (unless it is one made by Microchip Technology).

Answer (score 2):

It's short for ["Dual In-line Package"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package), a reference to the fact that the package has two straight rows of pins.

Comment: That stands for DIP. But what about DIP **IC**?

Comment: @DenisKulagin: "Integrated Circuit", as always.

Comment: Ok, I seem to get it. *DIC* stands for casing type and *IC* is that's is just a **microchip**.

Comment: @DenisKulagin there are DIP components that aren't ICs, e.g. DIP switches or DIP resistors, thus the distinction. Sometimes you also see "DIL" (Dual In-Line), which is synonymous with DIP.